# Command to measure CPU time and RAM usage of process while making sure it does not go over certain ressource limitation

Tags: bash, memory-management, shell

I found some old code of mine and am trying to see if it can be improved. The goal is to write a command that measures a process's CPU time and RAM peak usage and kills the process if it exceeds a specified amount of CPU time and RAM usage.

This command is meant to be used on both MAC OSX and Linux.

```
# Get arguments
MaxMemory="$1"
MaxTime="$2"
Command="$3"
for (( i=4 ; i<="$#"; i++)); do
    Command="${Command} ${!i}"
done

echo -e "MaxMemory = ${MaxMemory}\nMaxTime = ${MaxTime}\nCommand = ${Command}"


#### run the command in the background
${Command} &


#### Get pid
pid=$!
echo "pid = ${pid}"


#### Monitor resources
MemoryPeak=0
timeBefore=$(date +"%s")
while true;do
    # Get memory
    mem=$(ps -o rss= -p $pid)

    # Break if the process has stopped running
    if [[ ${mem} == "" ]]; then
        break
    fi

    # Set the MemoryPeak of memory
    if [ "${mem}" -gt "${MemoryPeak}" ]; then
        MemoryPeak=$mem
    fi

    # If it consumed too much memory, then kill
    if [ "${MemoryPeak}" -gt "${MaxMemory}" ];then
        #echo "process consumed too much memory"
        kill ${pid}
        break
    fi

    # If it consumed too much CPU time, then kill
    timeAfter=$(date +"%s")
    timeUsage=$((timeAfter - timeBefore))
    if [ "${timeUsage}" -gt "${MaxTime}" ];then
        #echo "process consumed too much time"
        kill ${pid}
        break
    fi

    # sleep
    sleep 0.1
done

timeAfter=$(date +"%s")
timeUsage=$((timeAfter - timeBefore))

echo "MEM ${MemoryPeak} TIME ${timeUsage}"
```

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Command="$3"
> for (( i=4 ; i<="$#"; i++)); do
>     Command="${Command} ${!i}"
> done
> # …
> ${Command} &
> ```

Much cleaner to just reference the end of the `$@` array directly.  Since you're running the commands later, and would like to keep quoting intact, use an array:

```
declare -a Command=( "${@:3}" )

"${Command[@]}" &
```

---

> ```
> # Break if the process has stopped running
> if [[ ${mem} == "" ]]; then
>     break
> fi
> ```

The idiomatic way to test for process existence is with `kill -0`, as in:

```
 kill -0 $pid || break
```

Since `$mem` is a number, or empty, an arithmetic test is good too:

```
(( mem )) || break
```

---

> ```
> if [ "${mem}" -gt "${MemoryPeak}" ]; then
>     MemoryPeak=$mem
> fi
>
> if [ "${MemoryPeak}" -gt "${MaxMemory}" ];then
>     #echo "process consumed too much memory"
>     kill ${pid}
>     break
> fi
> ```

Prefer parentheses over single brackets (or double brackets) for arithmetic operations:

```
 (( MemoryPeak = ( mem > MemoryPeak ? mem : MemoryPeak ) ))
 
 if (( MemoryPeak > MaxMemory )); then # etc.
```

---

> ```
>  # If it consumed too much CPU time, then kill
> ```

You're measuring wallclock time, not CPU time.  There's also some slop:  `timeBefore` is recorded when the script collects it, which might not be close to the binary invocation time.  Better to read the `times` and `cputimes` values from `ps`, and calculate with those:

```
 MaxElapsed= # …
 MaxCPU= # …
 # …
 read mem dt ct <<< $( ps --no-headers -o rss,etimes,cputimes -p$pid )
 # …
 if (( dt > MaxElapsed || ct > MaxCPU )); then # …
```

---

> ```
> timeAfter=$(date +"%s")
> timeUsage=$((timeAfter - timeBefore))
> ```

See timing comments above.  If you make the outer loop condition `kill -0 $pid`, you can simply reference `$dt` here.

---

### Putting it all together:

```
 MaxMemory=$1 MaxElapsed=$2 MaxCPU=$3 Command=( "${@:4}" ) MemoryPeak=0
 "${Command[@]}" & pid=$!
 while kill -0 $pid; do
    read mem dt ct <<< $( ps --no-headers -o rss,etimes,cputimes -p$pid )
    (( mem )) || break
    (( MemoryPeak = ( mem > MemoryPeak ? mem : MemoryPeak ) ))
    (( MemoryPeak > MaxMemory || dt > MaxElapsed || ct > MaxCPU )) && kill $pid && wait $pid  # loop conditional will break for us
done
echo "MEM $MemoryPeak ELAPSED $dt CPU $ct"
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of flattening arguments into the string `$Command`, I'd suggest leaving these arguments in `$@` by using `shift`:

```
MaxMemory=$1; shift
MaxTime=$1; shift
# Command is now in $@
```

(Alternatively, read `$1` and `$2`, then `shift 2` for the same result.)

We can produce output using portable `printf` instead of non-portable `echo -e`; it's probably a good idea to send these log messages to standard error stream rather than mixing them in with the program's output:

```
printf '%s = %s\n' >&2 \
       MaxMemory "$MaxMemory" \
       MaxTime "$MaxTime" \
       Command "$*"
```

We can now run the command very simply (with no breakage to quoted arguments):

```
"$@" &
```

Having done that, I recommend redirecting all of our subsequent output to avoid mixing it with the command's standard output stream:

```
exec >&2
```

We can replace the last remaining Bashism by using plain `[` instead of `[[`:

```
if [ -z "$mem" ]
then
    break
fi
```

or, more simply:

```
[ "$mem" ] || break
```

Now we can run with lower overheads using `/bin/sh` instead of needing Bash.

---

I do question the approach.  I think it's much simpler to use the existing `ulimit`, `timeout` and `time` utilities to achieve the same result:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

MaxMemory=$1; shift
MaxTime=$1; shift

printf '%s = %s\n' >&2 \
       MaxMemory "$MaxMemory" \
       MaxTime "$MaxTime" \
       Command "$*"

ulimit -v "$MaxMemory"
exec time -f 'MEM %M TIME %e' -- timeout "$MaxTime" "$@"
```

Although `ulimit -v` isn't specified in POSIX, it's accepted by many of the shells I tried, though not by Posh.  One limitation is that if `$MaxMemory` is too small for the shell, then it will fail before executing the command.  If we need to work with more shells or lower limits, then we could write a small wrapper program in C that calls `ulimit()` and `exec()`.